# Suming in an Array Formula using date based VLOOKUPs

Tags: google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

[This is the sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dqk0yLAm25hXG28pL_VBaIerbK7vuZ-_7SAYZ5onIfQ/edit#gid=920794725)

I have two data sets.

1. Cash balance recorded as a particular date
2. Cash added to the till

[image: Recorded Balance]
[image: Cash Added]

**Problem**
To be able to know the theoritical cash blance by adding new "Cash Additions" to the last "Recorded Balance" in chronological order.

[image: Expected outcome]

The intent is to know theorical balance since the last recorded balance event.

I have tried to use [Vlookup in Array Formulas for Dates](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/lookup-date-between-two-dates-in-google-sheets/)

But got stuck with summing values from "Cash Additions" with an Array Formula

Any particular suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,B2:B+IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 QUERY({IFNA(VLOOKUP('Cash Added'!A2:A, 
 SORT('Recorded Balance'!A2:A), 1, 1)), 'Cash Added'!B2:B}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col1
  label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Cheers. I will try get my head around this and might ask for a few clarifications on whats going on. I am little new advance manupulations with functions